# How do I implement 'fuzzy' search with the Solr search API

Tags: 8, search

Some sources equate 'fuzzy' search with matching partial terms (substrings), others include matching misspellings, also, as being 'fuzzy' search. I want to do both.

I have configured partial word matching, so that a search on 'break' will return results for content that includes the term 'breakpoint'. See [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2009760#partial-matches).

How do I configure Drupal/Solr so that a search on 'Brasil' will return results for content that includes the term 'Brazil'?

I am running:

- Search API: 8.x-1.0-beta4
- Solr search: 8.x-1.0-beta1

I added the following to schema.xml, under the first occurence of `<filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>` within the field type `<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">`:

```
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="25" side="front" />
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="25" side="back" />
```

So, a search on 'hell' or 'ello', for example, returns reults for 'hello - but a search on 'hillo' returns nothing.

I've found the below on [d.o](https://www.drupal.org/node/375446), but I'm not sure it refers to solr:

> Fuzzy Searches
>
> Lucene supports fuzzy searches based on the Levenshtein Distance, or
>   Edit Distance algorithm. To do a fuzzy search use the tilde, "~",
>   symbol at the end of a Single word Term. For example to search for a
>   term similar in spelling to "roam" use the fuzzy search:
>
> roam~
>
> This search will find terms like foam and roams. An additional
>   parameter can specify the required similarity. The value is between 0
>   and 1,, and with a value closer to 1, only terms with a higher
>   similarity will be matched. For example:
>
> roam~0.8
>
> The default value is 0.5 if the parameter is not given.

I'm not convinced this is even possible. Thanks.

Comment: Have you copied the necessary conf files to Solr from the module for the applicable version?

Comment: I am using the config files which come with apache solr 4.3.0, not the ones provided by _Search api solr search_ module.

Comment: You need to use the ones in the module. Check the readme

Comment: At the bottom of README.txt there is a section called _Customizing your Solr server_ which suggests to alter the xml files in the Solr configuration, which has been my approach. What is special about the config files that come with the module?

Comment: That readme contains _"The schema.xml and solrconfig.xml files contain extensive comments on how to add additional features or modify behaviour"_ I am pretty sure they are referring to the xml-files shipping with the module, not the default solr ones. `What is special about the config files that come with the module?` They contain some logic to map Drupal specific types to solr types. For instance http://cgit.drupalcode.org/search_api_solr/tree/solr-conf/6.x/schema_legacy_fields.xml

Comment: I've read it. I cannot see anything that solves this problem.

Comment: Did you add the `EdgeNGramFilterFactory` filters to BOTH query and index in the schema? There are use cases where you would only add the filter to one or the other, but yours does not sound like that. With both query and index ngrammed, Brasil and Brazil would then match on a 3 character ngram 'bra'. You may also consider using the non-edge `NGramFilterFactory`.

Comment: Also consider that users who type exact matches into search boxes would generally expect to see those first in a result set, followed by those that match somewhat, and then less-and-less. Using ngrams produces a 'match' regardless of the completeness of the match. I wrote a [post on this subject](http://jacobsanford.com/drupal/solr/search_api/search_api_solr/2017/02/24/drupal-search_api_solr-ngram.html) earlier this year you may want to reference.

Comment: I added to just index, not query. I will read your article. Thanks.

Comment: If you do not add the ngram filter to the query, your example of Brazil/Brasil will not match as you desire, as the string won't be broken down into the ngram 'bra' to match. I may misunderstand your use case.

Comment: Did you try disabling of SnowballPorterFilterFactory? For me this was an issue.

Comment: This may be a useful link for some: https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr/issues/1414838.